# 301 Redirect is not working for Sub Directory and its URLS of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I recently added 301 redirect to all my site for non-www to www. It is working perfectly. But now, I installed another wordpress in www.example.com/directory 
301 is not working on this directory only. As, I had many other directories like www.example.com/dir1 dir2 dir3 and so on. And when I added 301 all of them are also working perfectly.

The only redirect problem is coming for the directory which is added after added 301 redirect.

**Information that you may need is:-**
=> Site is on Wordpress.
=> To redirect whole site non-www to www I added this code to .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

( which is working fine! )
=> Now, for that directory which is not working I added

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^example.com/technology/.*$         http://www.example.com/technology
```

(which I expected to change all internal links of technology and including technology directory to redirect from non-www to www [after reading from the existing solutions at stackoverflow] but, it is not working. )

Guide me kindly so that I may correct my mistake. 
Looking for the response. Thank You!

Comment: Add the same redirect 301 rules to the top of .htaccess file inside technology folder.

Comment: Same means ? One that I added before and second one for technology folder? Or just this one:- RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: The rewrite rule 301, not the redirectmatch.

Comment: I did and now it is saying: This webpage has a redirect loop